# Sql Server 2008 Triggers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table `Message` already has a trigger. Running successfully inside that trigger I have an `insert` statement:

```
Insert into tblSettlement (MessageID,Lat,Long) Select Messageid,y,x from inserted
```

On the table `tblSettlement` I have placed that trigger:

```
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AddSettlementOnINSERT]
 ON [dbo].[TblSettlement]
 After INSERT
  AS
 DECLARE @id Bigint, @Lat Float,@Long Float, @LocName Varchar(200), @Dist float,@upd    bit 
 Set @upd = (SELECT updated FROM inserted)
 SET @id = (SELECT MessageID FROM inserted)
SET @lat = (SELECT [Lat] FROM inserted)
SET @Long = (SELECT [Long] FROM inserted)
if (@upd = 0) 
begin
declare @table table 
(Location Varchar(200),Distance float)
insert into @table 
SELECT  top 1 Full_Name_nd, SQRT(
  POWer(69.1 * (lat - @lat), 2) +
   POWer(69.1 * (@long - long) * COS(lat / 57.3), 2))As distance
 FROM geodb.dbo.geonames where SQRT(
  POWer(69.1 * (lat - @Lat), 2) +
  POWer(69.1 * (@Long - long) * COS(lat / 57.3), 2)) < 1 
 set @LocName = (select location from @table)
 set @Dist = (select distance from @table)
 Insert into dbo.tblset2

 (Messageid,lat,long,settlement,distance)values(@id,@lat,@long,@locName,@Dist)
  end
```

However the problem is that whenever we enable above trigger, insertion stops working on `Message` table.

Meaning: we want to insert, after insertion taking few column values and try to update another table with in the same Table's Trigger. Which actually does not allow us to insert.

Comment: Can you run the `SELECT` query in isolation and verify the results? This clause - `where SQRT(POWer(69.1 * (lat - @Lat), 2) + POWer(69.1 * (@Long - long) * COS(lat / 57.3), 2)) < 1` looks suspicious to me.

Comment: What exactly happens? Is there an error message? There's not enough information contained in "insertion stops working....does not allow us to insert" to help diagnose. **Have you run your trigger's TSQL in an adhoc context to debug which parts might give you trouble?**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i have run the code in isolation and it works.... but poblem is that as & when we makes enable the Trigger record insertion in message table is stopped :( (that is being manage by back-end service)

Comment: So, you have a trigger that *correctly* deals with multi-row inserts on `Message`, and a broken trigger on `tblSettlement` that doesn't deal with multi-row inserts - `inserted` can contain multiple rows, you need to write your trigger to deal with this correctly.

Comment: Always test triggers with multiple row inserts/updates/deletes as well as single row ones.

Answer (score 5):

Your basic assumption about SQL Server triggers is wrong - you seem to be assuming (as many people do) that the trigger will be called once per row inserted - that is **NOT** the case!

The trigger will be called **once per statement** - that is, if your statement insert 20 rows at once, your trigger will be called **once**, and the pseudo table `Inserted` will contain **20 rows** in it.

As such, if `Inserted` contains multiple rows, your statement here will either fail miserably, or select an arbitrary, random entry:

```
DECLARE @id Bigint, @Lat Float,@Long Float, @LocName Varchar(200), @Dist float,@upd    bit 
Set @upd = (SELECT updated FROM inserted)
SET @id = (SELECT MessageID FROM inserted)
SET @lat = (SELECT [Lat] FROM inserted)
SET @Long = (SELECT [Long] FROM inserted)
```

You have to rewrite your trigger entirely, taking into account that `Inserted` can and will contain **multiple rows**.

Comment: Setting a scalar variable to a field in inserted or deleted is a sure sign the trigger is incorrectly written.

Comment: "select an arbitrary, random entry" - no, it's more fun than that - since there are 4 separate selects, we can get one random element from *any* of the inserted rows for each one - it's not guaranteed that the 4 selected values will be correlated.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yes, that's what I meant - you should put it more clearly - thanks! Whichever way those values are selected - this trigger won't work and won't do what it's supposed to do...